# Is there an R package for finding the maximum-area rectangle in a non-convex polygon?

Tags: r, algorithm, polygon-creation

Does anyone know if there is an `R` package out there with an algorithm which finds the largest rectangle within non-convex polygons? I have Googled, searched the [R Sig Geo archives](https://web.archive.org/web/20210624002420/http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/), and looked here on GIS Stackexchange to no avail.

Here is an example of the type of output I am looking for:

[image]

This image comes from [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210730033922/https://d3plus.org/blog/behind-the-scenes/2014/07/08/largest-rect/) which showcases the type of algorithm that would be useful for my project. Unfortunately for me, that [algorithm](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507013845/https://d3plus.org/assets/posts/largestRect/src/largestRect.coffee) is written in `coffeescript` and I do not have the time to spend recreating it in `R`.

Comment: The related threads at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60755, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27303, and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32552 might be of interest.  Please note that the referenced algorithm is *approximate*: it performs a grid search over the range of possible orientations of the rectangle. This means the part you need to worry about is the simpler problem of maximizing a rectangle *of a given orientation*.

Comment: If you can't find an appropriate R script, maybe this blog will help you utilizeCoffescript/js in R.  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/js/vignettes/intro.html